# Any way to have Spring Data Auditing populate Long or String depending on field?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I've got a legacy schema which I'd like to use Spring Data JPA with, and I'm trying to work out if this scenario is possible.

I've code models like:

```
@Entity
class Entity1 {
   ...
   @CreatedBy
   private String createdBy;
   ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
class Entity2 {
    ...
    @CreatedBy
    private Long createdBy;
    ...
}
```

I would like to be able to use Spring Data for this, however I can't find a way (so far) to have the auditing support this.

First thing I tried is having two `AuditorAware` beans, however this results in a multiple bean exception problem.  Does anyone know if this is possible at present, and where I need to look for the solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting question, thank you for raising it.

Looking through the code, there is no way to plugin a second AuditorAware bean and have the system select between them by return type.
Spring builds even its own internal beans based on this assumption.

You would have to (based on a preliminary research):

- create an interface similar to AnnotationAuditingConfiguration interface that is aware that there are several beans of type AuditorAware
- create an AuditHandler implementation that can distinguish between AuditorAware instances, based on return type
- modify/override the AuditingBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport to construct the type-aware AuditHandler mentioned earlier
- provide an annotation that imports the overridden registrar

Quite a handful :))

Comment: Thanks for the information, Gabriel :)

I've actually gone ahead and raised a feature request in the Spring JIRA for this, as I'm sure it's functionality that others could take advantage of: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-540

In the meantime, I've used the AuditorAware beans from Spring, and written my own entity listener which does the same job as Spring Data, but in a very specific implementation to my needs.  I hope to replace this with the Spring Data implementation down the track if that feature goes ahead.

Comment: Nice, it would be really cool if you could share the implementation with us :)

Comment: I will do shortly, although I wouldn't consider the implementation to be a good example of how it should be done... it just works :)